# InnoDB recovery from datafiles

Tags: data-recovery, innodb, corruption

First of all, my MySQL DB and Linux skills are not so good. I spent several days searching for a solution and tried several approaches. The following approach is the one I came furthest with.

My SD card, on which my MariaDB was installed, is corrupt. However, I was able to recover the /var/lib/mysql directory.

I set up a new Ubuntu installation and a clean MySQL database. 
After I copied the recovered database directories into the new folder (without ibdata) and restarted the database, I could see the tables but got the error '1146 table doesn't exist'.

Then I also copied the file ibdata and changed the permissions (chmod, chown, chgrp). But after that I can't start the MySQL service anymore. I get the following error:

[Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().

[ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot create log files in read-only mode

[ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Read only transaction

[ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.

[ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.

[ERROR] Failed to initialize builtin plugins.

[ERROR] Aborting

I tried innodb_force_recovery 0-6 without success.

Does anyone have a hint for me what the error means and how I can recover my database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your MySQL directory is in read-only mode: `[ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot create log files in read-only mode`. Be sure to have write permission for the directory and the files inside it.

That said, if your SDcard failed, chances are that data itself are  corrupted beyond repair.

Comment: I changed the permission for the whole mysql folder with: 

chmod -R a+rwX /var/lib/mysql

I get still the same error.

Comment: My database's running again. The problem was the permissions and a wrong owner group. 
Thank you!